# Neo4J upgrade: why are the user roles not transfered?

Tags: neo4j

When upgrading from Neo4J 3.3.3 community to enterprise (or even between the versions), I noticed that the users, user roles, and permissions are not transferred.

Is this normal?

Do I have to set up the users manually every time there's an upgrade because they are stored in a separate DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neo4j 3.x.x, user and authentication data is stored in various directories at `NEO4J_HOME/data/dbms`, so you need to make sure you copy this over when you perform an upgrade within 3.x.x, and to sync this yourself if you're using a cluster.

In Neo4j 4.x.x, we introduced the concept of the system database to hold user, database, and security data, and this is automatically synced to a cluster. For backup/restore/upgrade you will need to include the system database when you perform these operations.

So we didn't have the concept of a separate database for this before 4.0, it only lived within discrete files.